# Session Management Across Multiple Devices

Tags: user, session

Today users wish to be logged in across multiple devices. 
The fact that Joomla signs out a user from all devices when one device was signout is driving users crazy. 
Can someone please help me, and explain to me how I can make sure the user session is kept and terminated only in case the user clicked the logout button on a specific device (and will keep signed in on different devices) ?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please take the [tour] and perhaps write something into your profile while you wait for support.  If you have made any partial progress with your research, please include your findings as an edit on your question.  Please continue researching; if you manage to resolve your own question, it is totally legit to answer your own question to the benefit of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Force Logout for all Sessions?" option in "User - Joomla!" plugin.